# Text tag icon Inside floating Action Button instead of vector icons tag

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a FAB but I dont want to use the standard vector icons.

I have a set of designed icons which are in text format. In this code below the icons do not appear?

what's wrong in my code?

```
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import { getColor, getIcon } from '../../src/utils/Misc';

const ActButton = () => {
    return (
        <ActionButton buttonColor="">
        <ActionButton.Item style={styles.otherButton} title="New Task" onPress={()=> {}}>
        <Text style={styles.actionButtonIcon}>
            {getIcon('plus')}
        </Text>
        </ActionButton.Item>
    )
}
```

***This text tag icon works very well in the other views. but here it just appears as a crossed out box..

The getIcon code snippet:

```
 import Icons from '../../res/values/icons.json';


export const getColor = name => {
   return Colors[name];
   };
 export const getIcon = name => {
 return Icons[name];
  };
```

Comment: Could you paste `getIcon` code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

if it works in other views, but not this one... then the problem is most likely a mapping to your asset. Therefore, your problem will most likely be found in the `getIcon` function